# How to integrate frontend and admin theme together in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an application with admin in ruby on rails. Now I need to add front-end in that application. But I don't know how ingrate with both in a single application.

Comment: You need to use separate layouts for that.

Comment: That's ok. But what about controller and routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an "admin" area pretty simply once you know how. It all comes down to [*namespaces*](http://blog.makandra.com/2014/12/organizing-large-rails-projects-with-namespaces/), specifically:

```
#config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
   # Sets up "/admin"
   root "application#index" 
end
```

Namespaces are essentially "folders", which also influence the names of your Rails classes (for example, your `controller` class names).

This means you'll be able to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/admin/application_controller.rb
class Admin::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    layout :admin
    def index
       #do stuff here
    end
end
```

Your models will remain as they are now (no need to make them `admin` namespaced).

--

The above code should give you the ability to access `yoururl.com/admin` and have a controller/action to work with. Of course, this negates the fact you're going to have to populate this area with data & controller actions; it all works much similarly to a "standard" rails app once you get it working.

You'll want to check out these helpful resources:

- [ActiveAdmin gem](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin)
- [RailsAdmin gem](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin)
- [RubyToolbox Admin gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_admin_interfaces)
- [Railscasts Admin tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/19-where-administration-goes):

[image]